# Regular expression start and end with word

Tags: javascript, regex

The below code is full of string. I want to select `cbUserURLs` array variable.

```
var someurl =new Array('a','b'); 
var cbUserURLs =new Array('url1','url2',...); 
.. //some code
```

What is the regular expression should I use here?

Comment: @anubhava javascript. I just need regular expression

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service. Show us what you have tried and explain how it does and does not work. Examples of things that should and should not match would really help.

Comment: "I just need regular expression" - No you don't! What you *do* need though, is to explain *what* you're trying to achieve, not *how* you think it should be achieved. It will make your question clearer and you might be surprised to learn other ways to achieve the same result, ways you haven't thought about.

Comment: @alfasin i just want to select a sting of `var cbUserURLs =new Array('url1','url2',...);` form the text

Comment: You want to select a string - by which criteria ? if you just want *any* string do `cbUserURLs[0]`

Comment: @alfasin check the edited question. the above javascript code in string type.. i want to trim the string where to start in ``cbUserURLs` to `);'` Hope now you can understand my question

Comment: No, it's still unclear. And changing the code formatting to a quote doesn't make it any clearer. Best advise I can give you is to ask someone you know to go over your question and see if they can understand what you want - then ask them to help you re-write it.

Comment: What do you mean, you want to select it? It's code, you don't have to select anything, you have what you want in a variable.

Comment: @DaveNewton the code is in string format.. after matching the string i want to execute `eval('string')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need use `cbUserURLs.*\);` if what you want is [image: this]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)